# How to properly use CountDownLatch for testing specific thread interleaving

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to test a particular thread interleaving where one thread pauses right after checking if a key exists in a map, then another thread inserts a value to the map, then the first thread continues and potentially overwrites the value in the map if there isn't some kind of synchronization.

So I used 2 `CountDownLatch` objects to stop the main thread just before inserting the value to the map, to wait for the worker thread to call the containsKey method and then the worker thread waits for the main thread to finish inserting the value to the map after which it continues.

The test works great if there is no synchronization and the expected exception does isn't thrown.

However, when there is proper synchronization (by defining the `register` method as `synchronized` for example) the test would (obviously) become deadlocked if it weren't for the busy wait loop.

My question is - is there a way **without using a timeout or a busy wait loop** to make a thread wait for another thread to release it, **but only as long** as the other thread itself is **not blocked**?

```
package authentication;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

public class RegisterConcurrencyTest {

    static class AlreadyRegisteredException extends Exception {}

    static class Register {
        private final Map<String, String> map;
        public Register(Map<String, String> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }
        public void register(String name, String password) throws AlreadyRegisteredException {
            if (map.containsKey(name))
                throw new AlreadyRegisteredException();
            map.put(name, password);
        }
    }

    static class MockHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
        private final CountDownLatch waitForRegister, waitForContainsKey;
        private final Thread main;
        public MockHashMap(CountDownLatch waitForRegister, CountDownLatch waitForContainsKey, Thread main) {
            this.waitForRegister = waitForRegister;
            this.waitForContainsKey = waitForContainsKey;
            this.main = main;
        }
        private void busyWaitForRegister() {
            try {
                while (waitForRegister.await(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    if (main.getState() == Thread.State.BLOCKED)
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
            boolean result = super.containsKey(key);
            if (!Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("main")) {
                waitForContainsKey.countDown();
                busyWaitForRegister();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void register() throws Throwable {

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        final CountDownLatch waitForRegister = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch waitForContainsKey = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Map<String, String> map = new MockHashMap<>(waitForRegister, waitForContainsKey, Thread.currentThread());
        Register reg = new Register(map);
        Future<?> future = exec.submit(() -> {
            try {
                reg.register("Bob", "123");
            } catch (AlreadyRegisteredException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        waitForContainsKey.await();
        assertThrows(AlreadyRegisteredException.class, () -> reg.register("Bob", "456"));
        waitForRegister.countDown();
        future.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this: `if (map.containsKey(name))
                throw new AlreadyRegisteredException();
            map.put(name, password);` is completely incompatible with multithreading and always will be. Use the proper method (in this case, map.putIfAbsent and check the return value).

Comment: @rzwitserloot actually, my real code used `putIfAbsent`. I changed it to use `containsKey` and `put` on purpose in order to simplify my code for the question (otherwise it makes the mock more complicated).

Comment: @rzwitserloot And either way that's not the point of the question because the problem persists even if I simulate the pause inside `putIfAbsent` just after the thread checks if the value is already in the map.

Comment: @Holger it is a simplification because it makes it easier to demonstrate the example (the example is obviously not the point here). Regarding the "incomprehensible" sentence - the thread waiting is waiting for the other thread to release it (with the CountDownLatch). What I want is for the thread to wait for the other thread, but to stop waiting if the other thread itself becomes blocking (i.e. the thread's getState() = BLOCKING) - this is what I do there in a while loop, but with an annoying busy wait. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Sometime, language is very important. If you repeatedly talk about a thread that is “blocking”, every reader will wonder what that thread is blocking. The other thead? If you were using the term **blocked**, everyone would immediately understand that the thread is not blocking something else, but is itself blocked.

Comment: @Holger Aha I see now why it can be confusing... you are correct I should have written "blocked". I will edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your correctly, you want to provoke the error connected to the check-then-act anti-pattern of calling `containsKey` followed by `put`. It’s important to emphasize that there are other concurrency issues with using a `HashMap` (which is not thread safe) without additional synchronization.

You don’t need to wait for the other thread to become blocked, you just have to use the latches in a different way. E.g.

```java
static class MockHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    private final CountDownLatch waitForRegister, waitForContainsKey;
    private final Thread main;

    public MockHashMap(CountDownLatch waitForRegister,
                       CountDownLatch waitForContainsKey, Thread main) {

        this.waitForRegister = waitForRegister;
        this.waitForContainsKey = waitForContainsKey;
        this.main = main;
    }
    private void containsKeyReached() {
        try {
            waitForContainsKey.countDown();
            waitForContainsKey.await();
            if(Thread.currentThread() == main) waitForRegister.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        boolean result = super.containsKey(key);
        containsKeyReached();
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V result = super.put(key, value);
        waitForRegister.countDown();
        return result;
    }
}
```

which can be used with the simplified test method

```java
@Test
void register() throws Throwable {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    try {
        CountDownLatch waitForRegister = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch waitForContainsKey = new CountDownLatch(2);
        Map<String, String> map =
          new MockHashMap<>(waitForRegister, waitForContainsKey, Thread.currentThread());
        Register reg = new Register(map);
        Future<?> future = exec.submit(() -> {
            reg.register("Bob", "123");
            return null;
        });
        assertThrows(AlreadyRegisteredException.class, () -> reg.register("Bob", "456"));
        future.get();
    }
    finally { exec.shutdown(); }
}
```

which will reproducibly produce a failure, as the main thread does not get the expected `AlreadyRegisteredException`.

Note the differences:

- The `waitForContainsKey` latch has been initialized with two, to let both threads wait to reach the point after `containKey`.
- Then, the main thread will wait until the worker thread has proceeded until after the `put` operation. There’s no need for the initiating test method to `await` or `countDown` latches.
- By letting the lambda expression passed to `submit` return a value, it implements `Callable` instead of `Runnable` which is allowed to throw checked exceptions, so we don’t need to catch `InterruptedException`.
- The executor service should be shut down even in the erroneous case, as otherwise the idle worker thread will only terminate after a minute (don’t even know whether this time is officially specified)

In this specific example, the use of the latches will prevent other concurrency issues from the underlying `HashMap`. The fix for the code should be to use `putIfAbsent` *and* a `ConcurrentHashMap`, to perform the update atomically.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for. Also the tips are much appreciated. My actual code indeed uses `putIfAbsent` (or `computeIfAbsent` and such), and a ConcurrentHashMap but I couldn't figure out how to properly control specific thread interleavings that I wanted to create in order to test other code. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

you made a synchronization by yourself and after that added a java synchronization and as a result to get deadlock

your synchronization block another thread and java synchronization blocks the main thread

you need to use either java synchronization or your handmade one

I recommended removing your synchronization and keep the java one

for example

```
static class Register {
    private final Map<String, String> map;
    public Register(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }
    public synchronized void register(String name, String password) throws AlreadyRegisteredException {
        if (map.containsKey(name))
            throw new AlreadyRegisteredException();
        map.put(name, password);
    }
}
```

and use regular HashMap instead of MockHashMap

Comment: You are completely missing the point of my post. The deadlock is there on purpose. The whole point of the post is regarding how the testing can be done with a specific thread interleaving.